# Approach for caching data from data logger

Tags: c#, logging, caching, sql-server-ce

Greetings,

I've been working on a C#.NET app that interacts with a data logger. The user can query and obtain logs for a specified time period, and view plots of the data. Typically a new data log is created every minute and stores a measurement for a few parameters. To get meaningful information out of the logger, a reasonable number of logs need to be acquired - data for at least a few days. The hardware interface is a UART to USB module on the device, which restricts transfers to a maximum of about 30 logs/second. This becomes quite slow when reading in the data acquired over a number of days/weeks.

What I would like to do is improve the perceived performance for the user. I realize that with the hardware speed limitation the user will have to wait for the full download cycle at least the first time they acquire a larger set of data. My goal is to cache all data seen by the app, so that it can be obtained faster if ever requested again. The approach I have been considering is to use a light database, like SqlServerCe, that can store the data logs as they are received. I am then hoping to first search the cache prior to querying a device for logs. The cache would be updated with any logs obtained by the request that were not already cached.

Finally my question - would you consider this to be a good approach? Are there any better alternatives you can think of? I've tried to search SO and Google for reinforcement of the idea, but I mostly run into discussions of web request/content caching.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a very reasonable approach.  Personally I'd go with SQL CE for storage, make sure you index the column holding the datetime of the record, then use TableDirect on the index for getting and inserting data so it's blazing fast.  Since your data is already chronological there's no need to get any slow SQL query processor involved, just seek to the date (or the end) and roll forward with a SqlCeResultSet.  You'll end up being speed limited only by I/O. I profiled doing really, really similar stuff on a project and found TableDirect with SQLCE was just as fast as a flat binary file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track wanting to store it locally in some queryable form.

I'd strongly recommend SQLite. There's a .NET class [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0).